# catch C++ exception from CHECK macros of google logging library

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I'm using a library that makes use of google logging library to log errors and check assertion with the CHECK macros. In my code, I'd like to catch an exception when the CHECK conditions fail (e.g., when the applications fails to open a file because it does not exists), but even using `catch(...)` it does not catch anything and the program crash with no control.

Is there a way to catch exception when the CHECK macros fail? Or, if it is not possible, is there a workaround to handle these situations?

Comment: Is CHECK a compile-time or runtime evaluated macro?

Comment: It is a runtime evaluated macro (like ASSERT)

Comment: You're using Google code to handle exceptions?!

Comment: @KerrekSB Not me, I'm using a library that uses google logging library (https://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html) to CHECK conditions. Since I have to use that library in my code, I'd like to find a way to handle these CHECK failure.

Comment: Old question, but I just stumbled on the same problem. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [official document](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/doc/glog.html) of glog, you can use

> User-defined Failure Function

to replace the default exit() behavior.

Example:

```
   void YourFailureFunction() {
     throw exception();
   }
   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     google::InstallFailureFunction(&YourFailureFunction);
   }
```

However, the function is called in a destructor so the behavior might not be suitable to our needs. In my situation, the function is called twice and I have to implement some not-so-beautiful hack to prevent the exception being thrown twice.

```
bool alreadyThrown = false;
void YourFailureFunction() {
    if (!alreadyThrown)
    {
        alreadyThrown = true;
        throw exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to disable "CHECK" throw. Is there any other way besides using "InstallFailureFunction"?

Comment: But it still fails with termination of execution. Any tips or hacks from that time ?